# DATE_ADD Query on Laravel show unexpected results

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have this query on mySQL

```
SELECT updated_at 
FROM products
WHERE updated_at >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
GROUP BY day(updated_at)
ORDER BY updated_at desc
```

and I try to apply it on Laravel like this

```
$date = Products::select('updated_at')
            ->where('updated_at', '>=', 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)')
            ->groupBy('updated_at')
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
            ->get()
```

and the results on Laravel is show all data in updated_at column, not just 6 days before now. Is there anything wrong with my query on Laravel, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `whereRaw` instead:

```
$date = Products::select('updated_at')
                ->whereRaw('updated_at >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)')
                ->groupBy('updated_at')
                ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                ->get()
```

Comment: I want to select the day of updated_at, how to do it?

Comment: I think you can use `Products::select('updated_at',DB::raw('DAY(updated_at) as day'))`

Answer (score 0):

Another use case is when you need to actually add an interval to a date column and compare that to now(), like comparing 2 days after start_date to now().
You would have to do exactly like this (laravel 5.7):

- where 'start_date' is the column name,
- keywords 'interval' & 'day' must be lowercase (or any other similar needed keywords)
- and brackets surrounding comparison date

```
->whereRaw('start_date + interval 2 day >= ?', [now()]);
```

I found the working answer here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/adding-days-to-a-date-in-a-where-query